# Show that $S$ is subset of f$^{-1}(f(S))$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, functions

Here is the full question:

> Let $f : X → Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$ , let $S$ be a subset of $X$, and let $U$ be a subset of $Y$. Show that $S \subset f^{-1}(f(S))$

My main problem is that I am not able to translate my reasoning to a formal Mathematical proof, here is what I am thinking of:

Every element $x \in S$ has a forward image $f(x)$ , $f^{-1}(f(S))$  will either return the same set $S$ (in case the function is one-to-one) or will return a set with more elements than $S$ (function isn't one-to-one, multiple inputs mapping to one output) where all elements of $S$ are in this set along with another new elements, either way all elements of $S$ will be in $f^{-1}(f(S))$ which is the definition of a subset.

What I tried:

I tried going back to the original definitions of a forward and inverse image in a way that I start with an element $x\in S$ and prove it's in $f^{-1}(f(S))$ but I can't see it using the formal definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition: $f^{-1}(B)=\{x \in X \, | \,  f(x) \in B\}$. So
$$f^{-1}\left(f(S)\right)=\{x \in X \, | \,  f(x) \in f(S)\}.$$
Let $a \in S$, then $f(a) \in f(S)$, this means $a \in f^{-1}\left(f(S)\right)$. Hence $S \subseteq f^{-1}\left(f(S)\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $f^{-1}(B)$ is the set of all the elements $a$, such that $f(a)$ is in $B$. So you just need to prove that for any $s \in S$, $f(s)$ is in $f(S)$.